# Contour Integral of Exponential

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

I want to show the following for $a > 0$:

$$e^{-a} = \int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}e^{-a^{2}/(4x)}dx}.$$

Comment: It seems that you're missing a factor of $\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: That might be true. Do you have a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not at the moment.

Comment: I tried using a contour that is like a quarter circle with a smaller quarter circle cut out at the origin in the "first quadrant" but that just told me that my integral is equivalent to the integral $e^{-2\sqrt{a}}\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{(x+\sqrt{a}/x)^{2}}dx}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(x+a^2/4x)}}{\sqrt{x}} \ dx  = 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(t^{2}+a^{2}/4t^{2})} \ dt$$

In general,

$$ \int^{\infty}_{0} e^{-ax^{2}-b/x^{2}} \ dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp \left[ -a \left(x^{2}+\frac{b}{a}\frac{1}{x^{2}} \right) \right] \ dx $$

$$ = \exp\left[ -a\left(x^{2}+\frac{b}{a} \frac{1}{x^{2}} - 2 \frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}} \right) - 2 \sqrt{ab}\right] \ dx= e^{-2 \sqrt{ab}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp \left[ -a\left(x- \frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}} \frac{1}{x} \right)^{2} \right] \ dx $$

$$ = \frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}} e^{-2\sqrt{ab}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp  \left[ -a\left(\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}} \frac{1}{u}- u \right)^{2} \right] \frac{du}{u^{2}}$$

$$ \implies \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax^{2}-b/x^{2}} \ dx = \frac{1}{2} e^{-2 \sqrt{ab}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left( 1+ \frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}} \frac{1}{x^{2}}\right) \exp \left[-a \left(x- \frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}} \frac{1}{x} \right)^{2} \right] \ dx$$

$$ = \frac{1}{2} e^{- 2\sqrt{ab}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-at^{2}} \ dt = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} e^{- 2 \sqrt{ab}}$$

Therefore,

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(x+a^2/4x)}}{\sqrt{x}} \ dx = \sqrt{\pi} \ e^{-2 \sqrt{a^{2}/4}} = \sqrt{\pi} e^{-a}$$

Comment: The 5th line following the implication arrow does not make sense to me. In the line before, it seems that you left u be a constant divided by x. Then, what happens to the u^2 term on the bottom? How did that become what you have in the next line?

Comment: $$\int^{\infty}_{0} e^{-ax^{2}-b/x^{2}} \ dx = e^{-2 \sqrt{ab}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp \left[ -a\left(x- \frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}} \frac{1}{x} \right)^{2} \right] \ dx $$

And 

$$ \int^{\infty}_{0} e^{-ax^{2}-b/x^{2}} \ dx =  \frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}} e^{-2\sqrt{ab}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp  \left[ -a\left(\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}} \frac{1}{u}- u \right)^{2} \right] \frac{du}{u^{2}} $$

$$ = \frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}} e^{-2\sqrt{ab}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp  \left[ -a\left(u-\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}} \frac{1}{u}\right)^{2} \right] \frac{du}{u^{2}}$$

Then I just added the two equations.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know of a way using contour integration?